# How to make UI which can fit to all screen size in android with one xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm making a app which can fit to all screen sizes. By creating different folder like:
layout
layout-small
layout-normal
layout-large
layout-xlarge
it working to all screen sizes but for that i have to make the same xml file in all folders. 
My question is without creating other layout folders is it possible to with one xml to fit the UI in all screen sizes.

Comment: make only one layout, use control's height, width match parent or wrap content. if using any images than add images in different drwable according to density

Comment: @justDroid in small screen it would work ?

Comment: ofcourse that will wok.

Comment: maybe [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/index.html) will help - the idea is to offer different layouts **if needed** and using the xml for things which do not have to be changed at runtime makes the code easier to read... after you get used to the notion that there is an xml file in addition to the java code ;)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html check this link.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the following attributes:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Hope it helps